# How to handle time offset in the past with boost odeint?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a harmonic oscillator with the latency tau in the coupling.

```
dx/dt = -y(t - tau)
dy/dt = x(t - tau)
```

How may I encode this in odeint ?

Do I have to save the computed states and interpolate the value of x and y at time t-tau ?
Would this work ? Do I have to use a special stepper to do so or use fixed steps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, this is a delay differential equation (DDE). Recently, there has been a similar question an SO [1]. Odeint does not support DDEs directly. But you can use the techniques you have so far described: Save the state and/or interpolate.

An alternative is to include the complete discretized history into the state.

[1] [DDE using boost odeint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572694/dde-using-boost-odeint/21576417)